# How to revert back my Windows 7 after installing Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, windows-8-preview

I already had installed Windows 7 on `D:` partition. I installed Windows 8 Developer Preview on C: drive but I can't dual boot Windows 7 and Windows 8, it directly boots to Windows 8. My D: partition contains all Windows 7 files. How do I access Windows 7 again?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/the-complete-guide-to-windows-8-startup-menu/) - press F8 while starting. And do try to research/say what you have tried, that was the first Google result I had.

Comment: Alternatively, try [this](http://lifehacker.com/5840387/how-to-dual+boot-windows-7-and-windows-8-side-by-side) (step three).

Comment: Or this...http://www.howtogeek.com/75878/how-to-uninstall-or-remove-windows-8-from-your-dual-boot-setup/

Answer (score 1):

Download [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net). It comes with Dual-boot Repair tool.

First run Dual-boot Repair -> "Automatic Repair" - this will fix boot environment (if any errors).

Then run Visual BCD Editor. RightClick -> Select "Create missing Windows loaders" (this will add boot entry for Windows 7 and any other installed Windows system XP, Vista, Windows 8).

To set Windows 7 as default:
click on Windows 7 in treeView - in Object tab - Set as default loader.

Reboot you should have a dual boot menu.